Motion blur SVG filter not working in iPhone
I am trying to add motion blur effect while sliding images, it works fine in android and web, but not working in iPhone.
below is the codpen URL and FVG filter code.
https://codepen.io/VijayDhanvai/pen/KKOwJPe
 <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
           width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 1366 768" xml:space="preserve">
  <!-- Gaussian blur filter progression to animate -->
  <defs>
    <filter id="blur0">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="0 0" />
    </filter>
    <filter id="blur1">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5 0" />
    </filter>
    <filter id="blur2">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="12 0" />
    </filter>
    <filter id="blur3">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="20 0" />
    </filter>
    <filter id="blur4">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="35 1" />
    </filter>
    <filter id="blur5">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="50 1" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>

<div class="slider">
  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>


I've tried poking this lots of ways to get iOS Safari to render it - including trying to move the animation into SMIL within the filter. It just won't work.

@MichaelMullany i have also tried so many things in last 2-3 days but not found any working solution.
Thanks appreciated your efforts.
